# c# use hash table causes trouble for finding way in maze game

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, key, hashtable

I am still learning c# :-)
I have a Point class and try to find a solution for a maze with a bright search. However I have trouble with the hash table. In the 3rd round I got the feedback that the hash table doesn't have the key 1, 1, also it is already listed. Does anyone has an idea what I made wrong?

thank you:

My Point class:

```
public class Point
    {
        public int PlX {get; set;}
        public int PlY {get; set;}
        private string fig;

        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            PlX = x;
            PlY = y;
            fig = "@";

        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return PlX + ", " + PlY;
        }

        public void drawP()
        {
            SetCursorPosition(PlY,PlX);
            Write(fig);

        }
    }
```

my has table for 2nd run:
-INDEX- -KEY-   -VALUE-

```
    [0]:    2, 1    1, 1

    [1]:    1, 1    0, 1
```

and function with mistake in 3rd run:

```
void pruefPos(string[,] game, int PoX, int PoY, Point kPos)
        {
            Point ktPos = new Point(PoX, PoY);
            if (PoX>=0 && PoY>=0 && PoX <game.GetLength(0) && PoY<game.GetLength(1))
            {
                if (game[PoX, PoY] == ".")
                {
                    if(myH.ContainsKey(ktPos))
                    {
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myQ.Enqueue(ktPos);
                        myH.Add(ktPos,kPos);
                    }
                }
               
            }
        }
```

and my loop:

```
while (myQ.Count != 0)
        {
            var aktPos = myQ.Dequeue();
            int poX = aktPos.PlX;
            int poY = aktPos.PlY;
            
            
                pruefPos(maze, poX+1, poY, aktPos);
                
                pruefPos(maze, poX-1, poY, aktPos);
                
                pruefPos(maze, poX, poY+1, aktPos);
                
                pruefPos(maze, poX, poY-1, aktPos);
                
        }
```